# Using UploadCollection to upload files with ajax in sapui5 send broken files?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sapui5

Iam trying to use the UploadCollection with ajax in order to send files through a post request, but for some reason, the file get's uploaded but it can never be open o visualize since the file seems to arrive broken in the backend (sap gateway) side.

This is the way I'm getting the file using the UploadCollection

```
                new sap.m.UploadCollection({
                    id:                        'upFiles',
                    numberOfAttachmentsText:   'Adjuntar archivos',
                    showSeparators:            'All',
                    fileType:                  ['jpg','jpeg','png','pdf','ods','pptx','xlsm','docx','doc', 'odt', 'docm','ppt','xlsx','rar','zip'], 
                    noDataText:                'No se han cargado archivos todavia',
                    class:                     'docpago-upload',
                    uploadUrl:                 '/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZGWRE_WF_FILES_SRV/WfFileCollectionSet',
                    maximumFilenameLength:     120,
                    maximumFileSize:           10,
                    multiple:                  true,
                    uploadEnabled:             true,
                    terminationEnabled:        true,
                    change: function(oEvent) {

                        var file = oEvent.getParameter("files");
                        var numfiles = oEvent.getParameter("files").length;

                        if(numfiles > 10){
                            MessageBox.show("Máximo de cargas multiples permitido es de 10");
                            oEvent.setCancelBubble(true);
                            oEvent.cancelBubble(); // para detener el proceso...
                        }else{

                            subeArchivos = true; 

                            $.each(file, function(i, val) {

                                console.log(val);

                                fixname = val.name;
                                filename = fixname.substring(0, fixname.indexOf("."));
                                extension = fixname.substring(fixname.indexOf(".") + 1);

                                //console.log('nombre archivo: ' + filename)
                                //console.log('extension archivo: ' + extension)

                                var obj = {
                                    'filename': filename,
                                    'extension': extension
                                };

                                files.push(obj);

                            });

                        }                           
                    }
                });
```

And this is the way Iam trying to send these files using ajax

```
                                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                                        url: sUrlUpload,
                                                        type: "POST",
                                                        data: file, //Files I want to upload
                                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                                        datatype : "text",
                                                        headers: {
                                                            'X-CSRF-Token': token, //token generated to send request
                                                            'slug': slug  //a parameter I need to do some stuff
                                                        },
                                                        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                                                            console.log('Uploaded files: ' + JSON.stringify(data));


                                                        },
                                                        error: function(oError) {
                                                            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(oError.responseText))
                                                        }
                                                    });
```

For some reason, In the sap gateway side, files are successfully uploaded but not even single one can be open because the programs say "invalid format", "corrupted file" etc etc.

What I'm not sure about? I was ask to send the files through ajax one by one, and in a xstring format. but I'm not sure how to get that xstring of every single file

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: there is no error message, I'm just getting "invalid format", "corrupted file"  when attempting to open the files

Comment: where are you trying to open them? I understood your issue, but its way too less context to help ... are the files arriving in the backend? do they get stored? from where are they opened? where's the issue, in backend or frontend?

Comment: I am trying to open them through a sap gatway, that is receiving these files from the frontend by using an ajax post request, the issue seems to be that the sap gateway is configured to receive these files in a binary format (xstring), so I need to be able to transform the file object I recieve as data from the UploadCollection once a (or mutiple) file is loaded, and then convert it in binary data that I can send so the sap gateway can recognize it and use it without problem

Comment: hi again, this is exactly the way it works. an xstring is a representation used to store a picture (as string) e.g. in a table. this means everything is working fine. I think you cannot "preview" the picture in SEGW. to preview the xstring, check this: https://answers.sap.com/questions/439233/how-to-display-an-image-in-container-saved-in-xstr.html